# VBA exiting loop at the last true condition

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building a macro that will look through a folder for all xls files of a certain report type and list them in a worksheet with the whole path. Then it ranks them in ascending order and finds the most recent file, which is opened and information from it is copied in a blank file as a process aggregating the most recent data from several kinds of reports.

The problem is exiting a loop once the most recent file has been found:

```
Dim i As Variant
Dim myarray() As Integer
Dim myarray2() As Variant

i = 0

For Each cell In Range("C1:C" & x)
    If InStr(1, cell, "proof") Then
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print i & " " & cell.value
        ReDim myarray(i)
        ReDim Preserve myarray2(cell)
    End If

    Do
    Loop Until InStr(1, cell, "proof")
Next cell
```

This is a trial code - it looks for all files that have `"proof"` in the filename in the specified folder and then prints them in the immediate window. A dynamic array stores each filename until the loop ends, and a `Do Until` loop routine is supposed to stop it at the last condition that checks as true - it being the file which will be then opened and info copied from. The issue is that the `Do Until` loop locks up the whole routine, since the first iteration that is true would satisfy it, and I'm not sure how to make it quit where it's supposed to...

A `Do-While` loop just ends up cycling on itself when put in the same spot.

Comment: I'm not sure how you determine the "last condition", but that `do` loop is pointless because it restarts for each `cell` and it has the same condition as the `if` above. The code inside the `if` does not make sense either. It would appear you want to remove the `do` loop, change the internals of the `if` to actually store the values in `myarray2`, let the `for` finish normally and then use the last element of `myarray2`.

Comment: The tested cell in your `do...while` never changes. So if the cell is not "proof" it is going to loop forever.

Comment: @GSerit, that's the thing - the last "proof" file gets stored in myarray2, but at the next iteration it is superseded by a file that does not meet the criteria, as the macro tests every file in the list. So, my conundrum is preserving the last file that has "proof" in the filename, while the loop goes through the rest of the list. That was the rationale of the Do-Until loop...

Comment: litelite, indeed. I'm not positive what the expression for the do-while loop should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't really get the whole of your aim. but you could try this for a start

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim myarray() As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim nFound As Long

    With Range("C1", Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference column "C" cells from row 1 down to last non empty one
        nFound = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, "*proof*") '<--| count occurrences of wanted substring
        If nFound = 0 Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if no occurrences
        ReDim myarray(1 To nFound) '<--| size your array to match occurrences
        Set cell = .Find(what:="proof", after:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, searchdirection:=xlNext) '<--| find first occurrence
        firstAddress = cell.Address '<--| store first occurrence address
        Do
            i = i + 1 '<-- update array index
            myarray(i) = cell.Value '<--| update array current index content
            Set cell = .FindNext(cell) '<--| search for next occurrence
        Loop While cell.Address <> firstAddress '<--| exit if occurrence wrapped back to the first one
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: CountIf is definitely better than testing for parts of a string in the range. Very cool way to go about it. The whole Do-While loop business makes a lot more sense following your example too. Thank you, user3598756!